# How to show a spinner while waiting for onAuthStateChanged() to resolve after signInWithRedirect()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jsx

I'm trying to set up a spinner, when the auth is changed. I've tried using the following method. (If spinner is true, it replaces the whole router component)

```
function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(false);
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSpinner(true);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        setSpinner(false);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ db, auth, currentUser, setSpinner }}>
      {spinner? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path='/'
              element={currentUser ? <MessageCenter /> : <Landing />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem I am facing here is, that on the first reload, the spinner doesn't show up but if I reload my page again, the spinner shows (as it is placed in use effect, in app.js) the onAuthStateChanged is supposed to be called each time the application is loaded (To set the currentUser, On logout or login) so for that, I'm using it in useEffect on the app.js.

Is there a way to show spinner while waiting for onAuthStateChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the spinner to show right after loading, did you consider giving it a default of `true`?

```
const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(true); //  set default to true
```

To hide the spinner:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  setSpinner(false); //  move this outside of the conditional
  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);
  } else {
    setCurrentUser(false);
  }
});
```

Comment: If I use this, that would basically mean whenever my page will be loaded, the spinner will be set as true by default. That would mean if the user will reload the page, it will show the spinner, permanently.

Comment: Did you try the code already? The spinner should only show until the auth state has been read. I added an update to show how to also hide the spinner when the user never signed in yet, which is another change needed from your original logic.

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely a silly mistake on my end. I've changed the code accordingly.